# Show that $(a) + (b)= R$ for $\gcd(a,b) = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, self-learning, gcd-and-lcm, principal-ideal-domains

The question I am trying to solve it:

> Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain, $a,b\in R$. Suppose $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. Show that $(a)+(b)=R$.

First I have tried to show that $(a)+(b)$ is in **R**:
  $\gcd(a,b)=1$ means there exists $s$, $t$ in **R** such that $as+bt=1$
  where $as$ is in $(a)$ and $bt$ is in $(b)$
  so $as+bt$ is in $(a) + (b)$ and since $1$ is in **R**, we have that $as+bt$ in **R** implies $(a)+(b)$ is a subset of **R**.

Then I want to show the other inclusion that **R** is in $(a)+(b)$ but I am not sure how to do this?

Comment: On this site we use MathJaX write maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can find a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious that $(a)+(b)\subseteq R$.
The other inclusion in the point of the question, and you (almost) proved it! From $as+bt=1$ we get $asr+btr=r$ for any $r\in R$, so $r\in (a)+(b)$.